# Save file on another computer through Java

Tags: java, mongodb, download

I am working on the following system:

- **DatabaseContainer**: on this machine I have installed MongoDB
- **Worker**: this machine downloads documents so as to store them on *DatabaseContainer*

The two computers are Linux machines in the same network, I can reach them through SSH, they can see each other via SSH, and SSH access if protected via private key.

Text files and HTML files are directly stored in MongoDB on *DatabaseContainer*.

---

However, I would like to download and store PDF files too. If I ask *Worker* to download files as follows:

```
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, new File(path + fileName));
```

the files are obviously stored on *Worker* and not in *DatabaseContainer*!

How to fix this and make my architecture store PDF files in DatabaseContainer?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you map a network drive to the other computer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use remote copy or ftp, the library for 'common' file methods is:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/index.html

Comment: I did not get how. Details?